# converting string.json() to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json

So I want to convert a python script to javascript. The script features a post request, which is supposed to send only a string. I found somewhere that stringname.json() somehow works(which it does), but I am not sure how it works. How do I replicate this in javascript?
Code:

```
user_info = requests.post('url',
               headers=headers,
               json = username.json()
```

Edit: This was a dumb question, ignore this

Comment: So you are writing nodejs code?

Comment: no, its vanilla js. I use fetch and already have the rest of the code, I just need to figure out the username.json()

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: So you are making a fetch() request then from the browser? What does your javascript attempt look like? Have you looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: ```
fetch("url", {
  method: "post",
  headers: headers
})
```

Comment: What does `username.json()` return (i'm asking for the exact value it returns; don't just say  "it returns json")? Python's `str` doesn't have a `.json` method afaik

Comment: so I have now realised that .json() was not after the string, but the request (got confused in the brackets). I still dont get why it works when it is present, but does not when i remove .json()

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` returns a `Promise`, so you need to either `await` it in an `async` function or use `.then`

```js
const userInfo = await fetch('url', {
  method: "POST",
  headers: headers,
  body: JSON.stringify(username),
}
```